# Select Duplicate Points PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a table made of merged point datasets in PostGIS.  I want to select all of the features where two or more points have identical geom values.

At present I just want to select so I can review the associated field values.

Comment: The geometries are now all in the same column? They're simple points, multipoints or something else?

Comment: yes, a single table exists, it has simple points with geometries all in the same column

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not all the details are clear, but my general approach would be along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM thetable AS a, thetable AS b
WHERE ST_Equals(a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id <> b.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name, p1.<other attrib>, p2.id, p2.name, p2.<other attrib> 
FROM points p1, points p2
WHERE ST_Intersects(p1.geom, p2.geom) AND
p1.id <> p2.id;
```

Some notes:

- With a large number of points you'll probably want to implement a
  spatial index on the table.
- Also this will find only points that **exactly** match. Sometimes very small rounding errors can create pairs of points which are essentially overlapping, but the coordinates are different by 0.1 mm or so, and the above will **not** find that pair. So perhaps wrapping one of the points with a small buffer, or running ST_Dwithin() with a small tolerance might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer can help to find points which overlapped with each other
[How to find overlapped points in postGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913335/how-to-find-overlapped-points-in-postgis)