# Get latitude and longitude of each point forming a MultiLineString

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

A MultiLineString is formed by a sequence of points and each point has latitude and longitude. 
Use the sql below to get the latitudes and longitudes of each point so that my MultiLineString:

```
SELECT
    St_AsText (ST_Transform("public"."Shapes".geom,4326)),
    "public"."Shapes"."id"
FROM
    "public"."Shapes"
```

[image: Result]

I want to get the sequence of points of each line in separate rows and lat / long in separate columns example:

```
   ID            pt_lat            pt_lon
   1001             lat1             lon1
   1001             lat2             lon2
   1001             lat3             lon3
   1001             lat4             lon4
   1001             lat5             lon5
   1001             lat6             lon6
   1002             lat1             lon1
   1002             lat2             lon2
   1002             lat3             lon3
   1002             lat4             lon4
   1002             lat5             lon5
   1002             lat6             lon6
```

I know I can do that consuming one GeoJSON for example, but want to know if there is a native function of PostGIS for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by looking at [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_DumpPoints.html), and this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41923/how-to-extract-point-from-a-linemultilinestring) might also help.

So select the id, dump the points, using st_x and st_y to get the lon lat